# Filter based on Foreign table data

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table Users and a table Staff. Users has one of the columns as TenantId and Staff has a UsersId foreign key. I use the following code to get the Staff and his User:

```
const listofStaff = await staff.findAll({
  include:[
           {
               model: Users, 
               attributes: ['TenantId']
           }] }
           )
```

This retrieves the following result:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "profession": "Dentist",
    "locations": "1",
    "services": "1",
    "note": "Good Man",
    "holidays": "Saturday",
    "createdAt": "2022-12-14T10:30:54.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-12-14T10:30:54.000Z",
    "roleId": null,
    "UserId": 1,
    "timesheetId": null,
    "User": {
        "TenantId": 1
    }
}
]
```

What I want to do now is add a Where condition based on TenantId, for example:

```
WHERE: {TenantId: 2}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily add conditions in `include` option just like you do on the root level (next to `include`:

```js
const listofStaff = await staff.findAll({
  include:[
           {
               model: Users, 
               attributes: ['TenantId'],
               required: true,
               where: {
                 TenantId: tenantId
               }
            }]
           })
```